# VLOOKUP() on every other column

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a time series with unmatched dates in the sheet `dataset`:

[image: dataset]

I want to use a `VLOOKUP` to return the price at each date or `ERROR` if the price is not available in the following way:

[image: output]

I want to use the following formula for the first row:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,dataset!A:B,2,FALSE), "ERROR")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,dataset!C:D,2,FALSE), "ERROR")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,dataset!E:F,2,FALSE), "ERROR")
```

I only show 3 columns in the example above but in the actual sheet, I have over 1000 columns. Dragging the first formula to the right actually gives:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,dataset!A:B,2,FALSE), "ERROR")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,dataset!B:C,2,FALSE), "ERROR")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,dataset!C:D,2,FALSE), "ERROR")
```

which is not what I want, the columns I want are `A:B`, `C:D`, `D:E`, `F:G`, etc. Is there a way to extend this formula over to the 1000 columns?

Comment: Drag to two thousand columns and delete every column where `=COLUMN()` is even (or odd)?

Comment: Thank you. This method worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be over thinking it but this should work:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,INDEX(datasheet!$A:$AAZ,0,1+(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2):INDEX(datasheet!A:AAZ,0,2+(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2),2,FALSE),"ERROR")
```

Put this in the upper left of the data output and drag across and down.  It should increment every two columns for every one it is dragged.

You may need to change the `$AAZ` to the last columns of your dataset.

---

This shows that the basic of the formula works:

I used the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(1,INDEX($A:$AAZ,0,1+(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2):INDEX(A:AAZ,0,2+(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2),2,FALSE)
```

In I2 and dragged it across.

[image]